# Symbolic dynamics for geodesic flow in hyperbolic space

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I'm working on a project in which I'm investigating some concepts related to ergodicity. I got to this point through some "usual" channels: continued fractions, the Gauss-Kuzmin theorem, its proof using Birkhoff's ergodic theorem, and further examples of ergodicity, including the ergodicity of geodesic flow in hyperbolic space. The last topic I'd like to investigate builds on geodesic flow in hyperbolic space, and, as far as I'm aware, is often referred to as the "symbolic dynamics of geodesic flow (in hyperbolic space)". Unfortunately, though, I don't have any good resources I can use to study this topic, so I was wondering if anyone here might be able to point me in a more promising direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some of the answers in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566342/how-does-symbolic-dynamics-contribute-to-the-study-of-dynamical-systems) might be useful.